# the type "any [] | undefined" cannot be assigned to the type "any []"

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a new problem since i updated today my npm and all modules.
Everything worked before i did the update.

error is "the type "any [] | undefined" cannot be assigned to the type "any []""

code

```
    this.myservice.myfunction().toPromise().then((data)=>{
      this.variable = data;
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Promise rejected with " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

and in the service:

```
  myfunction(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.post<any[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/GetDataFromBackend`, {  }).pipe(
      map((res) => res),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

anyone an idea why i got this error after the update? How can i fix this? i got this at nearly every component and backend connection...

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/mMy9dm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.  ---  It could be that your previous compiler configuration did not use `--strict` or `--strictNullChecks` and now it does.

Comment: If it does turn out to be `--strictNullChecks`-related, I would not recommend simply disabling it, although that would be the most expedient way to recover the previous behavior.  The right way to fix it is to actually check for `null` and `undefined` in a way the compiler can understand, to avoid runtime errors where values are unexpectedly `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: i can tell you that the backend delivers a JSON string and so the value is not undefined or null ... i found out that the behaviour occurs just at arrays and not at single values ... does this help? it is not that easy to build a playground with a backend and so on.
i found out that in tsconfig.json file "strict" was set to true - if i set it to false i can compile my app again. how can i "repair" it the correct way?

Comment: Even if the value is not `undefined` or `null` at runtime, the typings for your code that produce the arrays might include `undefined` or `null` in the element type.  But without a [mcve] I can only guess.  If you disable `--strictNullChecks` in your compiler options (tsconfig.json file maybe?) it is almost certain that the error will go away, but to determine if that is actually the cause would require you to recover your prior version of the project to see if it used to be disabled.

Comment: What does `this.handleError` look like? Is it possible that it's being interpreted by the compiler as something that can return undefined? If you remove the calls to map and/or catchError, does the compiler warning go away?

Comment: this.handleError looks like:
```
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // console.log(error);

    // return an observable with a user friendly message
    return throwError('Error! something went wrong.');
  }
``` - but "throwError" is crossed out ... with message "The signature '(error: any): Observable<never>' of 'throwError' is deprecated."

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript error.  You can overcome the problem in several ways.

1: You can check for undefined like this:

```
    this.myservice.myfunction().toPromise().then((data)=>{
       if(data !== undefined && data !== null) {
          this.variable = data;
      }
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Promise rejected with " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

2-if you know the value will never be undefined you can force it with "!" like this:

```
    this.myservice.myfunction().toPromise().then((data)=>{
       
          this.variable = data!;
      
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Promise rejected with " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

3- you can change the type of the variable when you declare it to be like:

```
let variable: any [] | undefined = [];
```

I am sure there is a couple more ways to fix this issue. But these 3 are the most commonly used in my personal experience.

With the advantage that you dont have to disable nice features like "strict" globally in your project.

The point is to develop using a stricter strongly typed model and not to weaken your code by "lowering the bar" on the typescript.